# LARAVEL how to hide some of the relationship records?

Tags: php, laravel

For example, you have `Post` & `Comments` and `Post` can have multiple comments, but the given user can only see specific comments. How this can be done?

Let's imagine a situations where we have a user, post and comments, and the given user can see only comments their friends are created.

```php
// Post.php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

// User.php
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
}

// CommentPolicy.php
public function view(User $user, Comment $comment)
{
    return $user->friends->pluck('id')->contains($comment->created_by_id);
}
```

So, when we run `$post->comments` - can we run that policy on each record?

Comment: We need more information to clarify it. Which is your policy? Who can see those comments?

Comment: lmk if you need more info

Comment: Do you have a corresponding `show` method in your `PolicyController`?

Comment: No, I don't have the `show` method in my `CommentPolicy` - I haven't heard of that before. Where and when the `show` method is used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes) or [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) to define sets of constraints:

```
 /**
 * Scope a query to only include popular comments.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```

Usage:

```
$post->comments()->popular()->get();
```

Comment: Hmm, how does this answers my question? For example, if John Doe can access only comments their friend is created. This could be done quite easily from Policies but how to run the "view" policy on each relationship record

Comment: It depends of your model. Who can see the comments? Based on an id? Please update your question to be able to help you better.

Answer (score -1):

Either you can use scopes as mentioned in the other answer to this question.

or you may use filters in the relationship itself in following way:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->where('is_visible', true);
}
```

It will fetch all comments against the post which has `is_visible` set to `true`

Hope this will help you.

Best.

Comment: Same thing here: how does this answers my question? For example, if John Doe can access only comments their friend is created. This could be done quite easily from Policies but how to run the "view" policy on each relationship record